# how to pass environment variables to an aws batch job definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I want to define Environment Variables for an aws batch job I am running. Different ENV variables trigger certain parts of the code. When I add them in the Batch console they are not passed to the job definition container properties. I pass the variables in the same form that I am passing them into my Dockerfile: NAME=VALUE. Below is the output I get after both creating a new definition and creating a revision to an existing definition.

`"containerProperties": {
        "image": "docker-image",
        "vcpus": 2,
        "memory": 2000,
        "command": [],
        "volumes": [],
        "environment": [],
        "mountPoints": [],
        "ulimits": []
    }`

Is there a special syntax thats used for this?

Comment: Please demonstrate in more detail how you tried, showing code that does not work is OK for that. Showing desired output (i.e. how you want it to look, imitating the expansion of your environment variables.

Comment: In the aws Batch job definition console, under the Environment Variables section, I put NAME in the Key input box and VALUE into the value input box. I click save. And the json for the job definition does not include the variables.

Comment: Found a solution, I ran a lambda function calling the 'register_job_definition' endpoint and included the environment variables in the payload. 'containerProperties = {
            "image": "test-image",
            'vcpus': 1,
            'memory': 10,
            "environment": [{ "name": "please","value": "work"}]
        
    }' I checked my batch definitions and the new definition had the variables. Not sure why it did not work from the console though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a lambda function to start job. Python code looks like :

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('batch')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  response = client.submit_job(
   jobName='some-job',
   jobQueue='some-Queue',
   jobDefinition='some-job-definition:1') # 1 is a version
```

environment variables will be added in `client = boto3.client('batch')`
 from environment